# Искажение таблицы при печати

Tags: html, css

При печати строка разбивается на несколько строк. Данное искажение проявляется только при печати.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-xl mb-0 mt-3 d-print-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col1">Статус</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col2">Организация</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col3">Контактные данные</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-2 d-print-none col4">Событие</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col5">Менеджер</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col6">Сум.контракта</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 col7">Дополнительно</th>
        <th class="border-top-0 pl-1 d-print-none col8">Действие</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-month="11" data-parent="" data-user_id="28" data-amount="1218000" data-duty="7259999">
        <td class="p-1 col1"></td>
        <td class="p-1 col2"></td>
        <td class="p-1 col3"></td>
        <td class="pt-2 d-print-none col4"></td>
        <td class="pt-1 col5"></td>
        <td class="pt-1 col6"></td>
        <td class="pt-1 col7"></td>
        <td class="pt-1 d-print-none col8"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поправил

Comment: 1. В вашем коде нет того что на картинке. 2. Покажите CSS. 3. Из картинки вообще непонятно в чём конкретно вы видите проблему.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел причину. Удалил  data-parent="" и искажение ушло.